# T4 Template,debugging without error when save an error

Tags: t4

**Code [here](https://github.com/magicodes/Magicodes.NET/blob/master/Plus/Magicodes.Admin/Controllers/SiteAdminNavigationsController.cs.t4)!**

T4 Template,debugging without error when save an error!!!
The code I can make sure there is no problem,And the debugger is normal, files are generated!

ERROR:
T4MVCGenerateInfo`2[TModel,TDbContext]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TDbContext'

Error detail:
错误  4   正在运行转换: System.TypeLoadException: “Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingEB3B19F9ED2A1CD8FC4B21815C1AACB477DD055C49C5754AF0754E9D44596039EB9CA531F9F56BFB60B31D13311A2A84214359163B64F650FF3E2A2DDF6E869D.GeneratedTextTransformation+T4MVCGenerateInfo`2[TModel,TDbContext]”上的 GenericArguments[1] (“Magicodes.Admin.Models.AdminContext”)与类型参数“TDbContext”的约束冲突。
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingEB3B19F9ED2A1CD8FC4B21815C1AACB477DD055C49C5754AF0754E9D44596039EB9CA531F9F56BFB60B31D13311A2A84214359163B64F650FF3E2A2DDF6E869D.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.PerformTransformation() D:\CloudDriver\Git\Magicodes.NET\Plus\Magicodes.Admin\Controllers\SiteAdminNavigationsController.cs.t4  1   1   Magicodes.Admin

Comment: I have fought with T4 a lot and I would say post your question to T4 website and I think they can assist you.

Comment: Can you provide the official website addresses? I searched for a long time did not find.Thanks！

Comment: Here it is: http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html

Comment: I move the class(T4MVCGenerateInfo) to library from the t4 template file,problem solved.My English is very poor,Can you understand what I mean?